# canvas drawBitmap() gives different output

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-image, android-bitmap

below image and code see, if's give different output in different device.

bitmaptemplate= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.fb_template);

```
    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =   bitmaptemplate.getConfig();
    // set default bitmap config if none
    if(bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    bitmaptemplate = bitmaptemplate.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmaptemplate);

    Bitmap bitmaplogo=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.temp);

    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfi =  bitmaplogo.getConfig();

    if(bitmapConfi == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
     }

    bitmaplogo = bitmaplogo.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canlogo=new Canvas(bitmaplogo);

    canlogo.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    Rect dstRectForRender=new Rect(10,250,700,700);
    canvas.drawBitmap (bitmaplogo , null, dstRectForRender, null );



    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
   int spSize = 45;
    float scaledSizeInPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
            spSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paint.setTextSize(scaledSizeInPixels);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText("PRATIK N SANYAJA", 20, 900+100, paint);
```

[image]

Comment: so where is your `bitmaplogo`? i only see black rectangle

Comment: black rectangle is my bitmaplogo

Comment: bitmaplogo = bitmaplogo.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canlogo=new Canvas(bitmaplogo);

    canlogo.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? to draw a black rectangle? if so, what do you need a `Bitmap` for?

Comment: i put after slow this problem because i show user photo place of black image

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? to draw a black rectangle? if so, what do you need a Bitmap for? yes

Comment: i have no idea what you mean... user photo is a black rectangle?

Comment: again: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: yes user photo is black rect

Comment: i give up, sorry....

Comment: I am confused by your code and your request. First of all why do you create scaledSizeInPixels and apply it inside the paint's Text Size? Second, if you want to have a static width and height of your image just use LayoutParams.

Comment: sir how to use layoutparams ? i don't know this?